# Why does the compiler complain that Char and AnsiChar are incompatible when compiling MadRes?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I'm compiling MadRes, but the error is this:

```
Checking project dependencies...
Compiling Project1.dproj (Debug configuration)
[DCC Warning] madRes.pas(351): W1057 Implicit string cast from 'AnsiString' to 'string'
[DCC Warning] madRes.pas(351): W1057 Implicit string cast from 'AnsiString' to 'string'
[DCC Error] madRes.pas(519): E2010 Incompatible types: 'Char' and 'AnsiChar'
[DCC Fatal Error] Unit1.pas(7): F2063 Could not compile used unit 'madRes.pas'
Failed
Elapsed time: 00:00:00.6
```

and then shows me this part of the unit madRes:

```
   if GetVersion and $ 80000000 = 0 then
        result: = CreateFileW (fileName, c1, c2, nil, c3, 0, 0)
   else result: = CreateFileA (pchar (string (WideString (fileName))), c1, c2, nil, c3, 0, 0);
end;
```

The code is a program I found the exe goes well but the problem is when I want to compile from my computer.

someone could help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should download and install the current version of madCollection :  http://madshi.net/

It has long since been updated for unicode support - the line in question looks like this now :

```
result := CreateFileA(PAnsiChar(AnsiString(UnicodeString(fileName))), 
                                                       c1, c2, nil, c3, 0, 0);
```

Delphi's default strings (PChar, etc) changed in D2009 from Ansi to 2-byte unicode; this introduced a need to be explicit about Ansi-specific implementations (PAnsiChar, AnsiString) for compatibility.  If you are interested to read more, I think this article on EDN is probably a good start :

[Delphi in a Unicode World](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/38437)